# How do i route to the same page using a button in Angular 13

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, frontend

My project currently has a login page and a dashboard page which you can only access through the login.
In the dashboard page, you have a sidebar with different buttons, each corresponding to a component.
What i would like to happen is to have my application display the different components in the body of the dashboard when i click on their respective buttons. Instead, i am being redirected to a separate page entirely and losing my navbar and sidebar from my dashboard.

here is my code :

home-page.component.html (the dashboard basically)

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-sidenav></app-sidenav> 
<app-body></app-body>
```

navbar.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">    
 <div class="container-fluid">     
  <img src="https://www.tunisietrade.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/logo_TTN_vectorise-1.png" class="navbar-brand" height="50" width="110">      
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">         
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>      
 </button>      
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">        
 <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0"></ul>         
<form class="disconnect">          
 <button [routerLink]="['/login']" class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit">Disconnect</button>
</form>       
</div>     
</div>   
</nav>
```

sidenav.component.html

`<div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

```
<div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="border-right sidebar-col " id="sidebar-wrapper"  [ngClass]="status ? 'hide' : 'show'">
  <div class="sidebar-heading">Dashboard</div>
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush ">
    <a href="facture" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action element-red">Facture</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="fournisseur" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action element-red">Fournisseur</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="reglement" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action element-red">Règlement</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="banques" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action element-red">Banques</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="comptes" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action element-red">Comptes</a>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sidebar-col">
   
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="btn" (click)="clickEvent()"></button>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

body.component.html

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BanquesComponent } from './home-page/banques/banques.component';
import { ComptesComponent } from './home-page/comptes/comptes.component';
import { FactureComponent } from './home-page/facture/facture.component';
import { FournisseurComponent } from './home-page/fournisseur/fournisseur.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';
import { ReglementComponent } from './home-page/reglement/reglement.component';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './login-page/login-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component : LoginPageComponent},
  {path: 'homepage', component:HomePageComponent},
  {path:'facture', component:FactureComponent},
  {path:'fournisseur', component:FournisseurComponent},
  {path:'reglement', component:ReglementComponent},
  {path:'banques', component:BanquesComponent},
  {path:'comptes', component:ComptesComponent},
  {path:'login',component:LoginPageComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents = [HomePageComponent]
```

my dashboard :

[image]

when i click on any of the buttons, ie "Facture" :

[image]

i tried hardcoding the navbar and sidebar into every component i was trying to route to, but that didn't work and it seemed kind of a workaround the issue instead of a fix, which i'm trying to find.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the route components will be rendered inside the `router-outlet`. You can place that wherever you need them to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes should look like this to use the router-outlet declared in body.component.html:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component : LoginPageComponent},
  {path: 'homepage', component:HomePageComponent, children: [
      {path:'facture', component:FactureComponent},
      {path:'fournisseur', component:FournisseurComponent},
      {path:'reglement', component:ReglementComponent},
      {path:'banques', component:BanquesComponent},
      {path:'comptes', component:ComptesComponent}
  ]},
  {path:'login',component:LoginPageComponent}
];
```

And instead of href="reglement" in your sidenav.component you should use routerLink="/homepage/reglement"

Comment: this helped redirect the route back to the dashboard page, however, now the components display under the page. So when i click on "facture" for example, it displays "facture works" under the sidebar, not to its right.

Comment: Changing the home-page content to <app-navbar></app-navbar><div class="d-flex">
<app-sidenav></app-sidenav> 
<app-body class="flex-col"></app-body></div> should help to solve the layout issue

Answer (score 0):

You could probably solve this with a bit of content projection using `ng-content`. You can use it to do something like this (supposing that you want to render the route components inside the `sidenav-component`):

```html
<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sidebar-col">
   
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="btn" (click)="clickEvent()"></button>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ng-content select=".app-content"></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

And then inside your `home-page.component` you can do this:

```html
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-sidenav>
  <app-body class=".app-content"></app-body>
</app-sidenav>
```